# Trigger async validator only on blur

Tags: angular

I have an `<input>` which contains a phone number. The phone number is validated on server side (lots of business logic).

I made an async validator `PhoneNumberValidator`. As it calls the server, I want the validation to be triggered only when the user leaves the field (on blur).

The `FormControl` constructor contains 3 parameters :

```
constructor(
  formState?: any, 
  validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null, 
  asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null
);
```

1. The initial value
2. A validator OR an array of validators OR an `AbstractControlOptions` OR null
3. An async validator OR an array of async validators OR null

So, for the simple validators, it is possible to pass an `AbstractControlOptions` which contains the option `updateOn` which does exactly what I want.

Why isn't there such an option for async validators? Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: Have you tried it? I have used `updateOn` on a field, which includes both sync and async validators. Or do you mean that you **only** want it on the async validator, not the sync?

Comment: @AJT_82 If I put `{updateOn: 'blur'}` as the second parameter, the async validator is never called. There are no other validators on this field. Also, I checked that the `(blur)` event works on this field (a basic `<input matInput>`)

Comment: If you have no sync validators, then just set an empty array for that part :)

Comment: @AJT_82 The pb was that I was trying to pass the validator as the 3rd argument of the FormControl instead of passing it in the `AbstractControlOptions`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this by defining a FormControl on a FormGroup as such:

```
{
  controlName: new FormControl({
    validators: [ Validators.required, etc ]
    asyncValidators: yourValidatorFunction(),
    updateOn: 'blur',
  }),
}
```

Comment: I understood my mistake thanks to your example. If `AbstractControlOptions` is used, then the async validator must be passed also in `AbstractControlOptions` and not as the 3rd arg of the `FormControl` csontructor. This works like a charm now.

Comment: Always glad to help.

Comment: You save my life. Thank you.